# How to prevent codeigniter from creating Memcache directory

Tags: php, codeigniter, google-app-engine

I'm developing a web app using codeigniter. Codeigniter creates a folder in the application folder when I run it locally. However the same application throws an error on Google App Engine, the reason being GAE has a read only filesystem.

I'm trying to prevent codeigniter to create this folder but have not got any success so far.

P.S. I'm new to codeigniter.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10000491/how-to-turn-off-on-memcache-in-code-igniter

Does this help?

Comment: @RobinValk thanks for ur help. However, the reply in that link is very confusing. Can you please help me out?

Comment: You may wish to take a look at https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/CodeIgniter

Comment: @mars will thr be too many differences to the default codeigniter. Because I have a half developed application and I do not want to start fr scratch again.

Comment: Which cache driver are you using? Do you mind to share some snippets? Thanks.

Comment: @Mars U can find the error message over here - http://job-portal-preprod.appspot.com/pages/sitemap. I did not understand on what you mean by the driver. I do not mind sharing code, please do let me know which part you want and I will post it here.

Comment: @Mars I tried the codeigniter for google app engine however it prompted me to make a lot of changes to the app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the following line in your app/config/config.php should fix the problem.

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'memcached';
$config['sess_save_path'] = 'localhost:11211';
```

Note that it doesn't matter what value you set for `sess_save_path` as long as it has the format `<hostname>:<port>`.